# How to sort by date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sort the record by date. So in query where should i add filter ORDER By date DESC in the code below.

```
"SELECT * FROM user_daily_records  WHERE  users = '" . $admin->get_nicename() . "';"
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: add it after your where clause

Comment: ...but you should be using prepared statements rather than splicing together your query.

Comment: Have you tried order by date desc ? Or may be question is not clear

Comment: Thanks all of you. Cubi answer resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the query :

```
"SELECT * FROM user_daily_records  WHERE  users = '" . $admin->get_nicename() . "' ORDER BY date DESC;"
```